# Can Kernel Density Estimation be used to smooth 3D data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, kernel-density

I'm aware that KDE can be used to estimate the density of points in any number of dimensions. For example, if I use [the sklearn implementation in python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html), I can simply feed in 3D data, fit the KDE model to that data, and then provide a number of 3d samples to determine the density at each "location":

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = rng.random_sample((100, 3))
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(X)
log_density = kde.score_samples(X[:3])
print(log_density)
>>> [-1.52955942 -1.51462041 -1.60244657]
```

However, I want to find out how to implement KDE for non-parametric data smoothing instead of just estimating point density at specific locations.

For my purpose, the 3D data is comprised of two known independent variables and one noisy dependent variable that I need to smooth. My goal is find the most probable value for the third (dependent) variable, given the two known independent variables.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to directly accomplish this goal with KDE. The closest I seem to be able to get is simply sampling new values from the fit KDE model, analogous to below:

```
>>> kde.sample(5)
array([[ 0.6917335 ,  0.77460117,  0.73769328],
       [-0.11267688, -0.33081919,  0.10876896],
       [ 0.54494928, -0.73509494,  1.29402285],
       [ 0.5332751 ,  0.89391167, -0.44075935],
       [ 1.41718108,  0.95660198,  0.00481628]])
```

Perhaps I could extract the most probable values instead of random sampling of the model if I sample enough and do some statistics, but this seems inefficient because we're sampling from the underlying distribution, so the underlying distribution is already known. **It seems to me that it should be possible to feed in the first two variables and find the most probable value for the third variable**. Is this just not implemented using standard packages or am I missing something fundamental about the operation of KDE here?

Comment: You certainly can use a kernel density as you were suggesting; my advice is to state the problem carefully and then work out the solution for yourself. At that point you will be able to recognize whether any package does that same thing. If not, well, no worries, you have a solution already. About working out the solution, I think the quantity you are talking about is the conditional density, p(z | x, y), where x and y are the known variables and z is unknown. Write out the joint and marginal densities, p(x, y, z) and p(x, y), in terms of a summation over kernel densities and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert! Once I had the KDE model all set, I simply fed in a grid of the three variables that span the range of all the data the model was trained on to evaluate the joint density p(x, y, z) over the whole "cube" of the three variables. Then I transformed p(x, y, z) to p(z | x, y) simply by normalizing p(x, y, z) by the summed kernel density along the z axis at each point (x,y). Then, for each point (x,y) you can find the ensemble average to get the most probable value from p(z | x, y).

Comment: Glad to hear you got something working. Bear in mind that kernel densities are typically multimodal, so it's easy to make up examples in which the expected value is not anywhere near the most probable value. Since p(z | x, y) is a function of one variable (given x and y), you can apply a 1-d numerical maximization algorithm; I think numerical analysis textbooks will describe various algorithms. You'll want to start from multiple starting points, since, again, kernel densities are typically multimodal.